# WSO2 - how to access publisher and store on Azure-VM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

how to access   WSO2 - access publisher and store on Azure-VM. After running wso2server.sh, the publisher and store are running on VM private IP address however I want to access publisher and store on public IP address over internet on my local browser. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should uncomment `<MgtHostName>Your public ip</MgtHostName>` and set your Azure-VM public ip from the carbon.xml which you can find from this location `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml.`(https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Running+the+Product)

Also, you need to open the following ports to access the WSO2 APIM store and publisher.

- For https 9443
- For http 9763

Comment: thanks adding public IP address at <MgtHostName> resolved the issue. Now I am checking how to open 9443 and 9763 ports, any suggestion?

Comment: Opening the port is nothing to do with the APIM side. You should open the port from your Azure VM. Please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083782/windows-azure-virtual-machine-opening-a-port